# Unity 2D I made a falling meteor and I want meteor to destroy tiles that hits in a circle area

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, tile

How can I circularly destroy tiles with meteor. In other words how meteor destroy tiles circularly.I have this code and Debug.Log(Hit!) works but tiles don't die. How can I destroy them and if it is possible I need to destroy them not square by square but spherical. Thanks a lot.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class TilemapDestroyer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ContactPoint2D[] contacts = new ContactPoint2D[10];

    public GameObject particles;


    void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)

    {

        Debug.Log("Hit!");

        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Tilemap")

        {

            Debug.Log("Hit tilemap!");

            int contactCount = collision.contactCount;
            if (contactCount > contacts.Length)
                contacts = new ContactPoint2D[contactCount];
            collision.GetContacts(contacts);


            Vector2 hitPosition = Vector2.zero;
            for (int i = 0; i != contactCount; ++i)

            {

                hitPosition.x = contacts[i].point.x;
                hitPosition.y = contacts[i].point.y;
                collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Tilemap>().SetTile(collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Tilemap>().WorldToCell(hitPosition), null);
                var newParticles = Instantiate(particles, hitPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                 this.transform.position, this.transform.rotation);
                StartCoroutine(DestroyParticles(newParticles));

            }

        }

    }

    public IEnumerator DestroyParticles(GameObject particles)

    {

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        Destroy(particles);


    }
}
```

Comment: I want this happens like Worms game does

Answer (score 0):

Well my first thought is to attach a sphere collider to this meteor and then use Physics.SphereCastAll to affect all the tiles.
If you are new Raycasting in Unity I suggest first reading about it

Comment: i have already added collider and when meteor hits meteor dies. Thanks for Physics.SphereCastAll function I will try but does it effect composite collider.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:
After the meteor touches the ground, you use the Physics.CheckSphere() method to obtain all of the GameObjects in the range. The method takes the position, diameter and optionally a LayerMask as arguments. It returns an array of GameObjects. Now just list through the GameObjects in the array and using the Destroy() method you destroy them. (You pass the GameObject you want to Destroy in the method.)

I hope this helped. :)

Comment: is that method destroys tiles square by square, thanks for answer